# sql join issue, not able to retrieve records from table a which matches some condition in table b and all that Ids that present in table A

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I am writing a sql query to get all those records from table A which matches table b with certain condition, and all matching records from table a  Below is the code and tables

```
Table A

skey    OrderName    
100     Pen     
100     Cutter  
101     any    



Table b1

skey     Key    Count
100      True     2

  



SELECT distinct gmo.Skey,
    gmo.orderName
from Test_B gmc
inner join Test_A gmo
    on gmc.Skey=gmo.Skey
where gmc.Count >1 and gmo.orderName in ('Cutter')
```

Result I need is

```
skey   Ordername    Default
100       Cutter     True
100       Pen
```

I want to do this with a single query only please help

Comment: What have you tried? What is the condition you mention?

Comment: If there is a skey(id) which is occuring twice in table a, I check if this is present in table b , and then I have to check if OrderName has value as 'Cutter' , i want to add a True value to it . But i also need another value for skey that is 100

Answer (score 1):

Use left join - **[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=375c4c93d0e80dec4c29532b492b90db)**

```
SELECT A.Skey,A.orderName
from A
left join B 
    on A.Skey=B.Skey
where B.Skey is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

Inner join is fine just move the condition to the select, Ordering may be a problem.

```
SELECT  gmo.Skey,
          gmo.orderName,
          CASE WHEN gmc.CountS > 1 and gmo.orderName in ('Cutter') THEN GMC.KEYVAL ELSE '' END `default`
from T1 gmc
inner join T gmo  on gmc.Skey=gmo.Skey

 +------+-----------+---------+
| Skey | orderName | default |
+------+-----------+---------+
|  100 | Pen       |         |
|  100 | Cutter    | True    |
+------+-----------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

btw default is a reserved word and needs to be backticked.